# How to get rid of connection timeouts in MongoDB Compass Aggregation Builder?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I wanted to test some aggregations in Compass (community edition) that take much time to complete and got those silly "operation exceeded time limit".

Then I tried new 1.19.1 (stable) version since this allows to set a custom "Max Time" parameter. Great, I see MongoDB is actually works on query for a time that I set there. But Compass doesn't get the result of it because of connection timeouts now.

The error now is

> connection 84 to localhost:27017 timed out

How could I avoid this?

Comment: Could you add some code or configs?

Comment: The code may differ, and I talk for a general issue of timeout on a long query. I connect to localhost with default port and options. If you need a specific config — just let me know where can I find it.

Comment: The query on its own is to parse 92k documents by _$filter_ an array of subdocuments with a simple condition _$eq._ As I use _$group_ at the last stage, MongoDB have to parse them all, so sampling is not applicable.

Comment: For now there is no way to change compass timeout. What you can do is either improve your request to make it executable fast enough, either execute the request directly using mongocli (command line).